# Is poetry package incompatible with verse?

Tags: verse, poetry

Reading the `poetry` manual I cannot see any mention of it being incompatible with `verse`. On the contrary it states in the Introduction on p.2 that it is "modestly compatible". But when I try to compile a document which uses both, I get the following error:

```
Command \c@poemline already defined. \newcounter{poemline}
```

Does that mean that `poetry` cannot be used with `verse`?

Comment: I think by compatible it means here that similar document markup can be used with either package, not that you should load both

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but could not even get the `poetry` package to work. When I enter this Minimum Non-Working Example (C)(TM) it does not even compile: \documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{letter} \usepackage{poetry} \begin{document} \begin{poem} Here I begin it \\ Tere I end it \\- \end{poem} \end{document} > Environment theindex undefined. \renewenvironment{theindex} > Undefined control sequence. H > Undefined control sequence. T You might want to stick with `verse` which is known to work and is used extensively, unless more knowledgeable members know the trick to make `poetry` work

Comment: `Undefined control sequence. H` is not the format of a tex error message, it would show which command is undefined. The first error from `theindex` is because you use `letter` class, the `poetry` package assumes a class that defines an index, eg `article` (although if I change your example to `article` it runs without error but with the (major) warning `\end occurred inside a group at level 2`)

Comment: I compile the example with letter or article or book class, and the error I got is "Environment poem undefined." If the error is iqnored by pressing return in Texwork, it does compile and produce a pdf file.

Comment: Update: In TeXLive the MWE compile. But in MikTex the poetry has to be loaded specifying the path, e.g. \usepackage{C:/miktex/tex/latex/poetry/poetry}. I notice that recent MikTex distribution has an arabi package containing poetry.sty. In TeXLive the file is called arabipoetry.sty.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of `poetry`.

As David Carlisle observes, "compatible with" means that you can (mostly) use your poetry written with the `verse` package in mind with `poetry` instead; it doesn't mean you should load both of them.  In fact, you shouldn't load both of them; `poetry` is meant to *replace* `verse`, not supplement it.

David Carlisle was good enough to bring this thread to my attention, which means that the package now *does* work with the `letter` class, and any class that doesn't define an index.  `poetry` also doesn't throw warnings anymore, again thanks to David Carlisle.  v2.1 was just uploaded moments ago and should be available on CTAN shortly.

I am very surprised to see `letter` used for a MWE; I normally see `article`, and the package would have worked perfectly well with that class.

Comment: I used `verse` with great success up till now but I was given a requirement to include a list of poems and tried to use `poem`. I am getting the same error as the OP even though I am not loading `verse` at all. My document class is `memoir`, not `letter`. I am on texlive 2018. Any ideas? And frankly, assuming that letters can contain no poetry is strange.

Comment: When you have a chance, please take a look at the new question I have ascked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520435/201502