# Why does poetry package not work?

Tags: errors, memoir, poetry

This MWE throws an error:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{poetry}
\begin{document}

\centerpoemon{In the cavern}
\begin{poem}
In the cavern\\
In the canyon\\!
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

> Command \c@poemline already defined. \newcounter{poemline}

Why?

Answer (score 5):

`memoir` evidentally defines a counter `poemline`, but `poetry` also does.  I don't use `memoir`, so I didn't catch this as a potential conflict.

`memoir` is a common class that should certainly be accommodated; but pending a permanent solution, consider doing the following before loading `poetry`:

```
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{c@poemline}
```

This should prevent the error and allow `poetry` to operate normally.  I will upload an actual fix shortly, but this should do the trick for now.

EDIT:  I just uploaded a fix, which avoids the conflict with `memoir`.

Comment: Note that you should place those two lines *before* loading the `poetry` package. Moreover, I don't know if using the `savesym` package to save counters instead of symbols is adequate.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii Have you pushed it into TL 2018 as well?

Comment: @SuperAl Only the current year of TL will reflect changes pushed to CTAN. If you are using an older version you will need to download the new version yourself and install it in your local `texmf` folder.

Comment: @AlanMunn Why can it not be pushed into the previous versions of TL? Some of us are stuck with them due to being on older OSs and it is very onerous to upgrade.

Comment: When was `poetry` first released? currently `texdoc poetry` gives a date of 1 May 2019?

Comment: The version before this most recent upload was 9 Nov 2019.  May was v2.0.  The original release was 19 June 2017, according to the CHANGES file.

Comment: @NVaughan:  I don't know if `savesym` was designed for that, but when I ran it, it worked, so I posted it as a stopgap.

Comment: @SuperAl It's simply not practical for the TL volunteers to maintain backwards updates. See [Why does TeX Live "require" yearly updates?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017) for some discussion.

Comment: @AlanMunn When do the updates normally show up on CTAN after the maintainer pushes them? The last update that I can see is from Nov 10 2019.

Comment: @SuperAl Usually a couple of days. There's a bit of manual intervention required and it takes a little while to propagate to all the mirrors. If the maintainer publishes an announcement with the update, it will appear here https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann (but not every update comes with an announcement.)

Comment: Does the workaround I posted not work for you?  In any case, CTAN is a huge undertaking (as is TeXLive), and it's amazing that everything there works as well as it does.  I received notice about the update I just pushed today; I'd expect an announcement soon.  The CTAN volunteers deserve our understanding and, most of all, our support.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `memoir` class, which can typeset poetry with the `verse` environment:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\linenumberfrequency{1}
\verselinenumbersleft
\settowidth{\versewidth}{In the cavern}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
In the cavern\\
In the canyon\\!
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Which renders:

[image]

`Memoir`'s `\settowidth{\versewidth}{In the cavern}` command and the `[\versewidth]` argument amount to the `\centerpoem{In the cavern}` command of the `poem` package. (It might appear that you need more instructions with the `memoir` class to attain the same results as with the `poem` package; however, the difference mainly concerns the defaults: default line numbering frequency, line numbering position, etc.)

(See the [memoir](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) documentation, Ch. 14, for detailed instructions on how to typeset and tweak poetry text.)

In any event, better not use `memoir` with the `poetry` package.

Comment: You might want to delete this answer as the question was not about alternatives to `poetry` which we are aware of.

Comment: @SuperAl I will not---his example uses `memoir` and my answer replicates the desired result.

Comment: @SuperAl Alternative method answers are often appropriate anyway, but in this case since you are using a class with built in methods for setting poetry the answer is entirely appropriate.

Comment: @AlanMunn I am actually using `verse` and have been for quite many years, as it provides necessary extensions over `memoir`. But `verse` does not provide list of poems which `poetry` provides and my question was an attempt to follow up on another question which I posted as a comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515724/201502

Comment: @SuperAl You misspeak. The `memoir` version of `verse` provides much more than the standard environment. It does provide facilities for putting poem titles into the ToC (even if you don't like the way it does it) and it also shows how to produce an index of first lines. Perhaps `poetry` does both of these but I don't use it. Good on you @NVaughan.

Comment: That is not the same as a list of poems.

Comment: @SuperAl It's true that `memoir` doesn't provide a list of poems out of the box. It would require a little hacking of the poem titling commands, but it's definitely doable.  If you're interested you could ask a separate question asking how.